# How to prove that a sequence is divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For this question, I know that the sequence diverges, but I don't know how to prove it. Can anyone please help me out?

Determine whether the following sequence is convergent or divergent.

$\{\sqrt{n}+1\}$

$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sqrt{n} + 1) = \infty$

Comment: by the definition?

Comment: Ya, by definition

Comment: Can you write the definition in your question, and actually try some things with that?

Comment: I don't know where to start with this question

Comment: Looks like you've got the right idea! You just need to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n}+1\right)=\infty,$$ and you're done!

Comment: @dg123 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\sqrt{n}+1>\sqrt{n}\to \infty$$

thus we can simply prove $\sqrt{n}\to \infty$.

Then fix $M$ and find $\bar n$ such that

$$\sqrt{\bar n}>M\implies \bar n>M^2$$

Comment: What does the little hyphen on top of the n mean?

Comment: It’s is only a symbol, we can also use $N$, its the upper bound for which when $n\ge \bar n $ we have $\sqrt n>M$.

Comment: dg123 please remember that you can accept an answer among the given if it resolves the question, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: How does this proves that it diverges?

Comment: You find the prove in my answe following the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be a positive real number. Choose a positive integer $N$ such that $N>(L-1)^2$. Then for $n\geqslant N$, we have $$\sqrt n+1\geqslant \sqrt N+1>L,$$ and hence $\sqrt n+1\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: Where did $(L-1)^2$ come from?

Comment: $$
\sqrt N+1 > L \iff N>(L-1)^2
$$

Comment: So then is there anything after this?

Comment: Like how does it prove that it equals infinity?

Comment: For a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=+\infty$ if and only for each $L>0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $a_n>L$ for $n\geqslant N$.

Comment: Is that the definition for divergence of sequences?

Comment: Is it? How can you hope to prove something if you don't know what it is you're trying to prove?

Comment: Confirmed the definition, it makes sense to me now, thanks